# Hadoop and Spark Monitoring and alert tool(Open source tools)

Tags: hadoop, apache-spark, alert, monitoring

I have 3 node hadoop and spark cluster.Currently I am using sematext SPM trial version for it's monitoring.But I am looking for an open source tool(other than ganglia) which will provide monitoring and alert/notification(via email) about cluster.

Comment: Are you running vanilla Hadoop cluster? I used cloudera and they have their own integrated alert system. If you have bandwidth, you can write your own alerts using Nagios!

Comment: Thanks.No,It's not vanilla Hadoop cluster.If I use cloudera  I have to use versions which they are providing in their enterprise edition.I want to use different versions of hadoop and spark than that.I will try nagios.any other tool?

Comment: Sorry I have limited experience here.